# image downloading from URL in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using google chart functionality in iPhone app....I want to download image and put it into UIImageView from http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World ...
Is there any sample app for doing such functionality?or any other way to display charts in app?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would block, use NSURLConnection for non-blocking download

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World"]];

UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

myImageView.image = downloadedImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL]]`

Answer (score 0):

@iSwap - I know that why your code is not working.

i think you put an url as a string instead of url. 
as above code ----

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL]];
```

there is aURL that should be a url not a string, and u wrote it as a string like

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World"]];
```

you have been forget to convert this string into an url.

the right method will be like this-

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World"]]];
```

i hope you got it, and one more thing there is no difference between "willcodejavaforfood" and "CodeBrickie" code. just way of writing is little differ.